# OAuth 1.0 binary data upload with RESTful api

Tags: api, rest, oauth, binary, image

I have a DESKTOP application which interacts with a web service through their RESTful api and OAuth 1.0. I can use all the resources fine, authentication, get/post calls to retrieve and send simple text data etc, no problems there.

However, I'm struggling to send binary data. The service allows sending pictures. For one part, they have a non-OAuth api through which you can also send a file in plain binary, simply pass some params in the URL and put the entire binary file in the post.

Now to do this through the OAuth api, becomes an issue:

The service specifies the post needs 2 parameters (not to be included in the URL since this is REST, but in the POST parameters):

```
image   A binary file, base64 data, or a URL
type    The type of file that's being sent in. Accepted values: file, base64, url
```

So we have 2 parameters: image contains the file itself, and type would be "file" to specify binary. But how am I supposed to include this through OAuth? given that the -image- and -type- parameters (and their values) must be used to generate the base string for the signature, which is matched against the parameters included in the POST.. I can't include the entire binary there as a value for the image parameter; so how is it done in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm, their OAuth api expects the file as multipart/form-data with the variables there, and none in the base string for the signature (their non-OAuth api instead doesn't need multipart, so I expected their OAuth wouldn't either; their documentation is a bit lacking in this area).